# Shell script loop runs out of memory under CygWin

Tags: linux, bash, shell, memory, cygwin

I've written a shell script running under CygWin, the purpose of which is to monitor a file for changes.  If the MD5 hash fails to match the previous hash, it will execute a command to process the file.  I used a 1-second delay between checks of the hash.  This works great for several hours, but then gives an "out of memory" error and actually brings Windows 7 to its knees.

The script uses a loop within a loop; the outer loop is infinite by design, and the inner loop ends when it finds a non-matching hash and processes the file.  It broke while running the inner loop, without the file having been modified at that point in time.  The file was modified numerous times previously, triggering the code below the inner loop, but not around the time when the memory error occurred.

I am just wondering why the loops here are consuming increasing amounts of memory over time.  I'm assigning new MD5 values into existing variables over and over, not allocating new variables for each MD5 assignment.  (Right??)  Is 1 second perhaps too short a delay... does the system need time to deallocate something between each iteration of the inner loop?

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE_TO_CHECK=/mypath/style.less

echo "Reading hash for $FILE_TO_CHECK with md5sum"
MD5PRINT=`md5sum $FILE_TO_CHECK | cut -d " " -f1`

MD5PRINTNEW=$MD5PRINT

while [[ 1 = 1 ]]
do
        echo "Waiting for file to change..."

        while [[ "$MD5PRINT" = "$MD5PRINTNEW" ]]
        do
                sleep 1

                MD5PRINTNEW=`md5sum $FILE_TO_CHECK | cut -d " " -f1`
        done

        echo "File was modified ... Running compiler..."

        /mypath/lessc $FILE_TO_CHECK /mypath/style.css -x

        echo "Reading hash for $FILE_TO_CHECK with md5sum"
        MD5PRINT=`md5sum $FILE_TO_CHECK | cut -d " " -f1`

        MD5PRINTNEW=$MD5PRINT
done
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I can provide the exact memory error if requested, but I would need some help to know which logs (if any) in CygWin to look at, to dig around and find the error text.  (I'd rather not run it all day to reproduce the error again.  The error was definitely something related to my CygWin shell running out of memory.)  Thanks!

(If you propose a solution which involves increasing the memory available to CygWin, that seems illogical, because the script is gradually increasing its own memory usage over time.  Thus, such a solution would only delay the inevitable, I think.)

Comment: Which version of cygwin are you running? Have you tried this using a native Linux shell as well?

Comment: Using the very latest CygWin, just installed from their website a few days ago.  And I haven't tried other distros but I'm fairly sure this is a problem specific to CygWin.  Now I have posted the issue on http://news.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin and gotten some helpful replies there.

Comment: Glad you found out what it was, to bad it didn't have a good solution. Suggest you write an own answer to your question on stackoverflow with a sentence or two of what it was, with links to your post on the newsgroup.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a summary of the info found by boy uptown. For the record :)

The mail/thread to the cygwin mailing list describing this problem is located at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/134041

http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda is a link to the application that can cause this "bloda" issues with cygwin.